# Is it possible to migrate a question from worldbuilding stackexchange to another site on stackexchange?

Tags: support

I know its possible to move a person's question from worldbuilding stackexchange to meta worldbuilding stackexchange but I was trying to figure out how to migrate a question to another site on stackexchange such as philosophy stackexchange.  When I was about to vote to migrate a question I noticed it seemed the only site I could vote to have it migrated to was meta worldbuilding stackexchange.  Is it possible to have a question on worldbuilding stackexchange migrated to another site on stackexchange entirely such as as I said philosophy stackexchange?

Answer (score 3):

If the option is not proposed to you in the closing reasons, you will need a moderator to do it. You just need to flag it (in need of a moderator intervention) with a short explanation.

I think that graduated sites can migrate their questions without mod intervention but we are not quite there yet.

Answer (score 2):

First, this applies only to questions that are *off-topic* on Worldbuilding.  If a question is on-topic here, even if it would be better somewhere else, don't migrate (or request migration) -- the person asked it here and we'll keep it.

For questions that are off-topic here but on-topic somewhere else, you can use a custom flag to suggest the migration (as Vincent [said](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3296/28)).  You should also vote to close as off-topic.

Note that Stack Exchange generally discourages migrating *answered* questions, especially if there's an *accepted* answer.

When suggesting migration it's helpful to also leave a comment on the question about it.  That way others have a chance to either support the suggestion or point out why it might not be a good idea.  Moderators can then make use of that feedback instead of having to look up the candidate site's on-topic list and make a judgement about whether this fits.  The more help you give us, the easier it is for us to make the decision to migrate (or not).